# Как на русскоязычной клавиатуре макбука вводить символ \% (обратного слэша и знака процента)?

Tags: macbook

Как на русской раскладке (macbook pro 2017 ростест) вводить знаки обратного слэша и занака процента?
И есть ли такая же проблема на macbook не ростест версии? Кто сталкивался?

Comment: `13"` / `15"` ?

Comment: 15" Пятнадцати дюймовый

Comment: В чём проблема тогда? Для слеша есть кнопка отдельная, а процент это Shift + 5

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> — %

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> + <kbd>ё</kbd> — \

Это для раскладки Russion.

Если включить раскладку Russion PC
системные настройки -> клавиатура добавить раскладку

то все будет работать по стандарту

ё - на кнопке ~
\ на своей кнопке

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]